# row header values won't show in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a database application with VB.NET using SQL Server. The problem is the row header cells won't show the numbers i'm trying to add. when i do a debug with breakpoints it shows up in the row header cells, but after the debug is finished so do the numbers in the row header cells. The datagridview is on a child form loaded into a parent form

This is the code in the form load event for the child form

```
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).HeaderCell.Value = CStr(i + 1)
    Next
```

i used also this code

```
Public Sub AutoNumberDataGridRows(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)

    Dim rowNumber As Integer = 1
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For
        row.HeaderCell.Value = rowNumber.ToString
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

The code works in another application i made **not** using a MDI Parent form.
so i'm lost whats causing it. Is it something in the settings of the datagridview or the forms i have to change?

Comment: The RowHeaders dont show or those values dont display - it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: The values won't show inside the row headers

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem.

Had to set the Set the property EnableHeadersVisualStyles to False from the datagridview

and it was a scope problem i believe

had to create a new instance of the child form containing the datagridview, had to do that in the parent form

```
 Private form As New Form
```

and then in the mdiParent form load event

```
  form.Show()

  For i = 0 To form.datagridview.RowCount - 1
          form.datagridview.Rows(i).HeaderCell.Value = CStr(i + 1)
    Next
```

This time the rowheader numbers appeared